# Was Nun, the father of Joshua a righteous person?

Tags: sources-mekorot, yehoshua-joshua

I recall learning a long time ago that Nun, the father of Yehoshua was a righteous person. Is there a source for this idea?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/who-was-yehoshua-bin-nuns-father/20255?r=SearchResults#20255

Answer (score 2):

Presumably yes, as per the principle brought down in Sifree [133](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Bamidbar.133.1?lang=bi):

וכל מי שמעשיו סתומים מעשה אבותיו סתומים, והכתוב מייחסו לשבח – הרי זה צריק בן צדיק; וכל מי שמעשיו סתומים ומעשה אבותיו סתומים, והכתוב מייחסו לגנאי – הרי זה רשע בן רשע.
For all whose deeds and the deeds of whose fathers are veiled and who Scripture traces (to their forbears) for praise are righteous ones the seed of righteous ones; and all whose deeds and the deeds of whose fathers are veiled and who Scripture traces (to their forbears) for denigration are evildoers the seed of evildoers.

Comment: Who is מעשיו סתומים here? Not Yehoshua